# Como obtener la interseccion de 3 arrays

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist

hola tengo 3 listas de juegos, y lo que queria realizar es obtener la interseccion, osea los objetos de los 3 que sean iguales, e ignorar a las que no cumplen con las 3.

Estaba usando como interseccion de 2 listas el siguiente codigo:

```js
var a = [1, 5, 3, 4],
    b = [1, 4]

var result = a.filter(function(e) {
    return b.indexOf(e) == -1
});

console.log(result);
```

Pero no me esta funcionando, ya que realizo un if con el operador "&&" y me traen. Pero el problema viene, cuando a veces uno de los array esta vacio, o no tiene ningun elemento que sea igual, haciendo que se saltee. Si el array C, tuviera un elemento que sea igual a los otros, si lo toma

```js
var a = [1, 5, 3, 4],
    b = [1, 4],
    c = [6,9]

var result = a.filter(function(e) {
    if(b.indexOf(e) !== -1 && c.indexOf(e) !== -1)
    return e;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Es sencillo: `const comunes = a.filter(e => b.includes(e) && c.includes(e));`. Saludos

Comment: Prueba con: `const result = a.filter(e => b.indexOf(e) !== -1 && c.indexOf(e) !== -1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, siguiendo el ejemplo de Mauricio

```js
const a = [1, 5, 3, 4, 7];
const b = [];
const c = [6, 9, 7];

const comunes = a.filter(e =>
  b.length > 0 ? b.includes(e) : true && 
  c.length > 0 ? c.includes(e) : true );

console.log(comunes);  // [7]
```

El problema es que falla cuando es el array "a" es el que está vacio.

Entonces hay que crear una algoritmo que soporte que cualquier array esté vacío

Estos serian los pasos:

1. Unir todos los array en un solo
2. Usar reduce para agruparlos, indicando el valor (k) y las ocurrencias (v).
3. Luego filtramos cuando las ocurrencias son iguales a un factor
4. El factor es la suma del tamaño de los array, siendo que un array_vacio=0 y un array_no_vacio=1. Es decir y si hay uno vacío (cualquiera) y 2 con datos el factor es 2
5. Luego hacemos un map para retornar el array

```js
const a = [];
const b = [1,9];
const c = [1,6, 9, 7];

function interseccion(arr1, arr2, arr3) {
    let factor = 0 + (arr1.length > 0) + (arr2.length > 0) + (arr3.length > 0);
    return [...arr1, ...arr2, ...arr3].reduce((acc,item) => {
        let i = acc.find(x => x.k == item);
        i ? i.v++ : acc.push({ k: item, v: 1 });
        return acc;
    }, []).filter(x=> x.v==factor).map(x => x.k);
}

console.log(interseccion(a,b,c));
```

Comment: me funciono tu codigo, muchas gracias. igual use algo similar al tuyo. Ya que no explique esto antes, pero los array son arrays filtrados de una lista juegos. Asi que al estar vacio algun array, yo le cargo todos los valores de lista juegos, asi directamente el IF lo ignore y lo de como "true", enfocandose en los otros 2 arrays